Custom discount not showing on invoice
I have added a custom discount on order using below code and its working perfectly fine but when create invoice from admin then custom discount not showing.
File: app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/etc/sales.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/sales.xsd">
    <section name="quote">
        <group name="totals">
            <item name="prepaiddiscount" instance="Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Quote\Address\Total\PrepaidDiscount" sort_order="400"/>
        </group>
    </section>
</config>

then created the model
File: app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/Model/Quote/Address/Total/PrepaidDiscount.php
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Quote\Address\Total;


class PrepaidDiscount extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal
{

    public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    )
    {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
        
        $items = $shippingAssignment->getItems();
        if (!count($items)) {
            return $this;
        }
        $prepaidDiscount = 10;
        if($prepaidDiscount){
            $address             = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();
            $label               = 'Prepaid Discount';
            $discountAmount      = $prepaidDiscount;   
            $appliedCartDiscount = 0;
            if($total->getDiscountAmount()) {
                $appliedCartDiscount = $total->getDiscountAmount();
                $discountAmount      = $total->getDiscountAmount() + $discountAmount;
                $label               = $total->getDiscountDescription().', '.$label;
            }    
            
            $total->addTotalAmount($label, -$discountAmount);
            $total->addBaseTotalAmount($label, -$discountAmount);
            
            $total->setDiscountDescription($label);
            $total->setDiscountAmount(-$discountAmount);
            $total->setBaseDiscountAmount(-$discountAmount);

            $quote->setCustomDiscount(-$discountAmount);
            $quote->setSubtotal($quote->getSubtotal() - $discountAmount);
            $quote->setGrandTotal($quote->getGrandTotal() - $discountAmount);
            $quote->setBaseSubtotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal() - $discountAmount);
            $quote->setBaseGrandTotal($quote->getBaseGrandTotal() - $discountAmount);            
        }

        return $this;           
    }
}

But discount not showing while creating the invoice, Any idea what I am doing wrong??

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? If so, kindly share it.

Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78965101/custom-discount-not-showing-on-invoice for answer

In the sales.xml file you only add to code for quote total only,
you also need to add for invoice
<section name="order_invoice">
    <group name="totals">
        <item name="prepaiddiscount" instance="Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Invoice\Address\Total\PrepaidDiscount" sort_order="400"/>
    </group>
</section>

in the file Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Invoice\Address\Total\PrepaidDiscount.php
you need to do code like below
<?php

namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Invoice\Address\Totall;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice\Total\AbstractTotal;


class PrepaidDiscount extends AbstractTotal {


public function collect(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice $invoice)
{
    // your custom logic to set discount and total
    return $this;
}

}

To ensure that your custom discount is reflected in the invoice as well, you need to add the custom discount to the invoice totals. This involves extending the invoice totals collection process similarly to how you've done for the quote. Here's what you should do:

Update the sales.xml file to include the custom discount for invoices:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/sales.xsd">
    <section name="quote">
        <group name="totals">
            <item name="prepaiddiscount" instance="Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Quote\Address\Total\PrepaidDiscount" sort_order="400"/>
        </group>
    </section>
    <section name="invoice">
        <group name="totals">
            <item name="prepaiddiscount" instance="Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Invoice\Total\PrepaidDiscount" sort_order="400"/>
        </group>
    </section>
</config>


Create the PrepaidDiscount model for the invoice similar to the one you created for the quote:
File: app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/Model/Invoice/Total/PrepaidDiscount.php
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Invoice\Total;

class PrepaidDiscount extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice\Total\AbstractTotal
{
    public function collect(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice $invoice)
    {
        $order = $invoice->getOrder();
        $prepaidDiscount = $order->getCustomDiscount();

        if ($prepaidDiscount) {
            $invoice->setDiscountAmount($invoice->getDiscountAmount() + $prepaidDiscount);
            $invoice->setBaseDiscountAmount($invoice->getBaseDiscountAmount() + $prepaidDiscount);

            $invoice->setGrandTotal($invoice->getGrandTotal() - $prepaidDiscount);
            $invoice->setBaseGrandTotal($invoice->getBaseGrandTotal() - $prepaidDiscount);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}


Register the total collector for invoices in di.xml:
File: app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/etc/di.xml
<type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice\Total">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="totals" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="prepaiddiscount" xsi:type="string">Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Invoice\Total\PrepaidDiscount</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>



This ensures that the discount applied on the order is also applied to the invoice. The PrepaidDiscount class for the invoice works similarly to the one for the quote, adjusting the invoice totals based on the custom discount applied to the order.
